# Where can I find plant fiber?

Tags: starbound

I'm on one of the first few quests where I'm supposed to make a bow, kill an animal, and cook the food. However, I can't find plant fiber anywhere to make the bow with. Where can I get some?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some trees (which may not be present on every planet) yield plant fibre when cut down. Just use your matter manipulator.

Vines work as plant fibre. You can find those growing on cave ceilings. Cut them with the matter manipulator, too.

You can grow some yourself, which is renewable, but takes some time and requires some preparation. You'll need a few seeds (you start with those) and basic stone tools.

Comment: Plant Fibre can be grown like crops?

Comment: Not directly, but some crops yield it. Actually, let me double-check.

Comment: @Katustrawfic I just checked. Looks like it is not a 100% chance, but harvesting a certain crop (not specifying which because of spoilers -- and it may be true for all crops. I just tested the one I'm sure it happens with) sometimes yields fibre instead of the fully-grown crop. Although this *can* be a bug.

Comment: I've been paying more attention when harvesting crops now. It seems things that grow on stems tend to occasionally drop plant fibres.

Comment: It looks like the rules differ for each crop. Some yielded fibre *instead* of the usual crop when harvested, others yielded *both* the crop and fibre. In either case, the chance of fibre dropping seems to be around 1 in 3.

Comment: Trees and vines easier to cut with axe. Matter manipulator is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Wheat often drops Fiber, so farming wheat on a large scale could be a solution, assuming that you didn't manage to find one of the large flower-like trees (not available on all planets) that drop Fiber instead of Wood.

Answer (score 0):

the vines you see contain them, shoot them with your laser thing at the top of them or what hangs them and you get at least 5-9 for each one.

Comment: Can you properly name the "laser thing" and the thing that "hangs them".